# Wordpress Rewriterule / Redirection

Tags: .htaccess

Guys i'm facing an issue regarding wordpress redirection.

I've used .htaccess on my website and i wish to make this work also for wordpress pages.I've installed wordpress in a folder named as "blogs" on the root like /blogs

I've also integrated/made changes in search.php of wordpress (domainname.com/blogs/wp-content/themes/my_theme/search.php) to my requirements. When someone searches the form action goes some thing like this:
http://www.domainname.com/blogs/?s=keyword

This works fine but I want to use rewrite rule over this something like:

www.domainname.com/blogs/blog-keyword with http://

but it brings user to 404.php page of wordpress

my current htaccess file contains the following code under the blogs directory of root:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blogs/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blogs/index.php [L]

# Pads Landing / Searching Page
RewriteRule ^blogs/movie-(.*) /pads/?s=$1
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Kindly help me I've few mins left for project deadline.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok...

Check into **Options -Multiviews**

I've noticed issues when using wordpress

I use it like so

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine on
```

So

```
RewriteRule ^pads/movie-([^/]+)$ "http://%{HTTP_HOST}/pads/?s=$1" [R=301,L]
```

Hope it works. Lemeknow

Comment: also if your rewriting the base directory to /pads/ then maybe you don't need the pads/ at the beginning of the rewrite. I would assume that it would be treating /pads/ as the new index directory. Not sure.

Comment: Nops, this also fails to work for me...........Guys kindly take a look upon this issue and give me your best suggestions. Once again thank you for your contribution.